# What is the name of this PDE? And has any analysis be done on it?

Tags: differential-equations

$$i\hbar\partial_{t}\psi+(P_{r}+iP_{i})\partial^{2}_{x}\psi+(Q_{r}+iQ_{i})|\psi|^{2}\psi+(C_{r}+iC_{i})|\psi|\psi=(\gamma_{r}+i\gamma_{i})\psi$$

It is a generalization of the (1+1)-dimensional nonlinear Schrödinger equation.

Comment: Hi soot, welcome to MO. It would be helpful to provide some context such as where/how you found this PDE. Moreover, please explain what all the symbols represent (constants, variables, etc.). Also, it is much better to enter mathematical expressions using MathJax instead of linking to images.

Answer (score 2):

It is a cubic nonlinear Schrodinger equation even if you generalize the domain. However, the complex coefficients will play an important role in the analysis of this equation. Like, the energy estimate for example.